# Google cloud platform: unable to connect to compute instance via SSH

Tags: ssh, google-cloud-platform

I'm struggling to connect to my GCP instance via SSH. Connecting via SSH from the the web based console is fine, and I can connect using the Google cloud SDK shell from my laptop, which rules out a connectivity or firewall issue.

I've tried enabling os login:

[image]

I didn't really understand this so I tried adding SSH keys directly:

[image]

Here is the public key portion of my `id_rsa` file, copied from puttygen:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQD3u7O9pk3YtE10hjaRAWixkwAv6rvOIiMnF+KOQyO/MG8GcGKUypL3nNbotmvPu8hlROz/GghkkSxzp3Bubm+8K+K4A8s68tyUenYXZcdN71BOVnY1F23gt9FfwHO5n9M9nQQwwyHtVJtRF7RPPJpD8L3NO1M7YxKSoW10+omEOBhAjo5PS0pcaiaUoh5C9Z0+fpmZPuFEZ43w9MFxt5LPU/46LwoYCvNOGFICAHshpQRsl94v+QzHzAShCvwjPkCryMDFzLdOylIIua94ZlnYNWElSSNZ2nFRHGgbyqhYIYj4IMV1nNrh11bL6PgmW9Dq6pfz2KGrbrBMBJPRSkzZ imported-openssh-key
```

This comment ends with theuncated/tail output of my attempts to connect via SSH, but I ran the command with `-vvv` so it's very long.

```
    PS C:\Users\Ian> ssh -vvv ian_newson_gmail_com@[REDACTED]
*SNIP*
    debug2: languages ctos:
    debug2: languages stoc:
    debug2: first_kex_follows 0
    debug2: reserved 0
    debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
    debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
    debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
    debug3: send packet: type 30
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
    debug3: receive packet: type 31
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY received
    debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:lA8OfaT+zJSicRoNfgnnkHMofmihr8PcKngqlBObenk
    debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ED25519 in file C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/known_hosts:9
    debug3: load_hostkeys_file: loaded 1 keys from [REDACTED]
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/Ian/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts: No such file or directory
    debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
    debug1: load_hostkeys: fopen __PROGRAMDATA__\\ssh/ssh_known_hosts2: No such file or directory
    debug1: Host '[REDACTED]' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
    debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/known_hosts:9
    debug3: send packet: type 21
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
    debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
    debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
    debug3: receive packet: type 21
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
    debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
    debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:4RkpcJoekNd71rWzZU8Twwq3svIH9WgoOL35JSh83d8 agent
    debug1: Will attempt key: .\\gcp.openssh.key RSA SHA256:aMIaDYUExt0e4bAlx1+TXLtXFVvgksuGi+R3i5XWVTs agent
    debug1: Will attempt key: .\\ssh.key RSA SHA256:TMEoLGu61in1hlbW8jbAJ94TpmAL+9tbSf4mKMHJ2GQ agent
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_rsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug1: Will attempt key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
    debug3: send packet: type 5
    debug3: receive packet: type 7
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
    debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp256@openssh.com>
    debug3: receive packet: type 6
    debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
    debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
    debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
    debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
    debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
    debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:4RkpcJoekNd71rWzZU8Twwq3svIH9WgoOL35JSh83d8 agent
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: .\\gcp.openssh.key RSA SHA256:aMIaDYUExt0e4bAlx1+TXLtXFVvgksuGi+R3i5XWVTs agent
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Offering public key: .\\ssh.key RSA SHA256:TMEoLGu61in1hlbW8jbAJ94TpmAL+9tbSf4mKMHJ2GQ agent
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_rsa
    Enter passphrase for key 'C:\Users\Ian/.ssh/id_rsa':
    debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:4RkpcJoekNd71rWzZU8Twwq3svIH9WgoOL35JSh83d8
    debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:4RkpcJoekNd71rWzZU8Twwq3svIH9WgoOL35JSh83d8
    debug3: send packet: type 50
    debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
    debug3: receive packet: type 51
    debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_dsa
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ecdsa
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ed25519
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk: No such file or directory
    debug1: Trying private key: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_xmss
    debug3: no such identity: C:\\Users\\Ian/.ssh/id_xmss: No such file or directory
    debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
    debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
    ian_newson@[REDACTED]: Permission denied (publickey).
```

Here is some of the output from mu `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Apr 13 19:17:01 instance-1 CRON[12310]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Apr 13 19:17:01 instance-1 CRON[12310]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Apr 13 19:21:43 instance-1 sshd[12322]: Connection reset by authenticating user ian_newson [REDACTED] port 65262 [preauth]
Apr 13 19:21:47 instance-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Apr 13 19:21:49 instance-1 sudo: ian_newson_gmail_com : TTY=pts/1 ; PWD=/home/ian_newson_gmail_com ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/nano /var/log/auth.log
Apr 13 19:21:49 instance-1 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by ian_newson_gmail_com(uid=0)
```

Comment: The debug output from the ssh client is generally not useful. Look at the log output from the ssh server. That will tell you exactly why the authentication failed.

Comment: @JohnHanley the last line is `ian_newson@[REDACTED]: Permission denied (publickey)` However I posted the keys above and they seem to be identical.

Comment: The last line of what? Did you check the SSH server log files? Do not use the SSH client debug output. The server does not tell the client why the authentication failed.

Comment: @JohnHanley Ah I see. There are several log files of course, I added the tail from /var/log/auth.log to my question.

Comment: It does not help if you show the logs from a valid connection where you used nano to read auth.log

Comment: @JohnHanley that wasn't from a valid SSH connection that was from the GCP web console. I've solved it now anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using the gcloudsdk and monitoring it with `procmon`.

First use the gcloud SDK to create an SSH connection:

e.g. `ssh instance-1 --zone=us-central1-a`

This will then create a file called `~/.ssh/google_compute_engine.ppk`. Open this file with PuttyGen and use it to create an OpenSSH key by clicking `Conversions` > `Export OpenSSH key'.

This file can be used to connect to the instance using `ssh -i {filename} {username}@{host}`.